# Lodash how to get specific objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, frontend, lodash

Using **lodash** how can I get specific objects that is in an array. I've created array to compare it if the name is in array.
The array look like this.

```
[
    {id: 13, name: 'John'},
    {id: 15, name: 'Mike'},
    {id: 18, name: 'Kristine'},
    {id: 24, name: 'Peter'},
    {id: 33, name: 'Alex'}
]
```

This is the names I want to get

```
['John', 'Mike', 'Alex']
```

The result I wanted should be like

```
[
        {id: 13, name: 'John'},
        {id: 15, name: 'Mike'},
        {id: 33, name: 'Alex'}
]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use lodash for this? It's pretty trivial to use vanilla JS to accomplish this (i.e. `array.filter(obj => obj.name == 'John' || obj.name == 'Mike' || obj.name == 'Alex')`). If you have an array of names as you say, you could do `array.filter(obj => ['John', 'Mike', 'Alex'].indexOf(obj.name) > -1)`

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter

Comment: `array.filter(obj => names.includes(obj.name))` or - for linear performance on larger arrays - `names = new Set(names); array.filter(obj => names.has(obj.name));`

Comment: thanks for the help guys